# Laravel Passport: how to customize the authentication guard for the user provider in your application

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Laravel by default creates the model and the User table. The problem is that I create and use the table in the database, a model and a controller called `Citizen`.
And here comes my doubt, when we configure `laravel-passport` we must specify the guard, this is the Laravel example:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

What is the provider? Taking into account this line:

```
        'provider' => 'users',
```

Should I use `'provider' => 'citizen'`, instead of `'provider' => 'users'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom provider. This has to be done in config/auth.php
There is one provider named users by default. You can create your own guard and providers as follows:

guards:

```
    'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'citizens' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'citizens',
    ],
],
```

In the providers section:

```
   'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'citizens' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Citizen::class, //path to your model
    ],
],
```

Now you can use the middleware with custom guard by using `auth:citizens`  as middleware.
For example, in route file,

```
Route::middleware('auth:citizens')->group(function(){

});
```